# XSLT - Pairing the content of two nodes with multiple appearances into one output for each appearance

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm quite new to XSL and I got the following problem:

There is a XML file with lots of nodes in it.

```
<cruisecontrol>
 ...
 <sysinfo>
  <info/>
 </sysinfo>
 ...
 <vminfo>
  <info/>
 </vminfo>
 ...
 <sysinfo>
  <info/>
 </sysinfo>
 ...
 <vminfo>
  <info/>
 </vminfo>
 ...
 <sysinfo>
  <info/>
 </sysinfo>
 ...
 <vminfo>
  <info/>
 </vminfo>
 ...
</cruisecontrol>
```

The 'sysinfo' and 'vminfo' nodes occur more than once but both in the same amount in this XML file. Now I need to transform this file into a HTML file to display the results (cruisecontrol plugin). The problem is, that I want to pair the contents of 'sysinfo' and 'vminfo'.

All I got is sth. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>    

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <h1>System Information</h1>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//sysinfo"/>
  <h1>VM Information</h1>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//vminfo"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="sysinfo">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="vminfo">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="info">
  <xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Output looks like:

```
System Information
<sysinfo1>
 <info>
<sysinfo2>
 <info>

VM Information
<vminfo1>
 <info>
<vminfo2>
 <info>
```

But what i want is:

```
<sysinfo1>
 <info>
<vminfo1>
 <info>

<sysinfo2>
 <info>
<vminfo2>
 <info>
```

Is it possible, to get the 'info' from 'sysinfo' and 'vminfo' alternatingly?

Comment: Your question is not clear: do the `sysinfo` and `vminfo` nodes come in pairs? Or are they in separate blocks? And what is really the output you want? Your stylesheet says "html"  but it outputs text (and not the output you show). Please clarify.

Comment: 'sysinfo' and 'vminfo' are both childelements of 'cruisecontrol'. They both have multiple appearances and always come after each other(the first 'sysinfo' always belongs to the first 'vminfo', the second 'sysinfo' to the second 'vminfo' and so on, but they can be seperated by other childelements of 'cruisecontrol').  The output is going to be HMTL, but i removed the HTML parts from the code to make it shorter.

Comment: "*They both have multiple appearances and always come after each other*" This doesn't answer my question. Please edit your example so it contains at least two of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither your input nor the output is very clear. But at first sight, I think that changing the XSLT like the following can give an idea what can be done here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>    

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//sysinfo"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="sysinfo">
  <h1>System Information</h1>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>
  <h1>VM Information</h1>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::vminfo[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="vminfo">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="info">
  <xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Within `sysinfo`, you call the following `vminfo` which should lead to the alternation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works now. I started writing the XSL based on the w3schoosl tutorial but this tutorial is missing out the existence of sth like `following-sibling`

Answer (score 0):

Given an example input:

**XML**

```
 <cruisecontrol>
    <sysinfo>
        <info>S1</info>
    </sysinfo>
    <vminfo>
        <info>V1</info>
    </vminfo>
    <sysinfo>
        <info>S2</info>
    </sysinfo>
    <vminfo>
        <info>V2</info>
    </vminfo>
    <sysinfo>
        <info>S3</info>
    </sysinfo>
    <vminfo>
        <info>V3</info>
    </vminfo>
</cruisecontrol>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/cruisecontrol">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="sysinfo"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sysinfo">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="info | following-sibling::vminfo[1]/info"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<div>
   <div>
      <p>S1</p>
      <p>V1</p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <p>S2</p>
      <p>V2</p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <p>S3</p>
      <p>V3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```